# How to get current logged in user's omni -channel assigned work queue in lightning experience or apex or in VisualForce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, omnichannel

I want to fetch assigned cases or leads to a logged user in user in Omni-Channel, by using Lightning component or apex or visual force pages.

I tried many methods but I am not getting a response in return.

Please help.

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a work item is assigned to user through omnichannel. It creates one entry in Agent Work object.

If a workitem is in user omnichannel then agent work status is assigned.
If workitem moved to my work then agent work status changed to open.

Try to build custom logic on this object to get the cases assigned to user using omnichannel.

Comment: Thanks, bro it worked, can you please help me in one more thing, how can I get the user's recent omnichannel status.

Comment: I mean online, offline, Busy etc and also how can I change that status dynamically.

Comment: Try to work on this object, may be you get some crack with this object. I am not sure whether we can modify the presence status programatically.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userservicepresence.htm

Comment: Thanks mann, It really helped me alot.